# vSphere iPad Client performance graph scale?

Tags: ipad, vsphere-client

The vSphere client for the iPad is brilliant, however I'm having a bit of trouble determining the X-axis scale for the graphs.

[image]

What kind of time frame is that over? 5 minutes? 10 minutes? 1 hour? I've tried lining up its peaks in processor usage against our logging, but because VMWare only seems to be snapshotting every 60 seconds, and we snapshot every 10 seconds, it's pretty difficult to get any sort of average (plus the iPad is 10" and our normal performance graphs are 50" so you can't even kinda hold it up against the other graphs and squint, which I did try).

Does anyone know what time scale the performance graphs are over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be ~12 hours. We had some [anomolous events today](https://serverfault.com/questions/281329/erratic-cpu-usage-by-mscorsvw-exe-net-runtime-optimisation-service) which made it much easier to spot individual peaks in processor and disk usage, so I just kept zooming out until they seemed to line up. The magic timespan was 12 hours.